# /proc/version(Alpine Linux Distribution)

Tags: alpine-linux

I just had an interview where i was required to do some system admin tasks on an Alpine Distribution System.
I was given 20 mins and internet to solv the tasks.What i found was that for Alpine,"apk" is the package management command(from google),but it was un-available on the system itself,
Upon doing "cat /proc/version",i confirm the distribution was exactly the Alpine.
But,now since interview has been done with,i am still doubtful about "whether the system,i was handed was really an "Alpine Linux" or not.

So,Could someone please post the output of " cat /proc/version" from an Alpine distribution?

Would be a bit of relief for me,if i would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.32-0-hardened (buildozer@build-3-6-x86_64) (gcc version 6.3.0 (Alpine 6.3.0) ) #1-Alpine SMP Fri Jun 16 12:20:58 GMT 2017
```